# How to get android Toast Height before display

Tags: android, android-toast

I've been trying to get the height of a custom toast so i can display the toast at the top right of a button by using this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyToast {

    public static void showToast(Context context, View v, String s) {

        int pos[] = new int[2];
        v.getLocationOnScreen(pos);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_style, (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
        text.setText(s);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, pos[0] + v.getWidth(), pos[1] - v.getHeight());
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

I passed the view of the button so i could get the position i want to place the toast, but v.getHeight() is not the height needed to accomplish this task, any suggestions?

Here's the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/frame_outline" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toast_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried using text.getHeight() and layout.getHeight() but both result in zero

Comment: When the method is called? Maybe the view is not drawed yet?

Comment: Cant I retrieve the height of the view which is being created? It shouldn't have to be displayed to have a height

Comment: @Raddy post your xml

Comment: Even if passed a lot of time since the last time i develop with Android, I'm sure that Android will not report to you the height/width of a View until it doesn't draw it. And Android doesn't draw the view if it is not showed since is useless.

Comment: I guess that makes sense then but is there any way i can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ViewTreeObserver` to get the height of your textView without displaying in the screen through calling its `getViewTreeObserver` method and get the height inside the `onGlobalLayout` method of the `ViewTreeObserver`.

**sample:**

```
final TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
          text.setText(s);
          final ViewTreeObserver observer= text.getViewTreeObserver();
           observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                 Log.d("Hieght", ""+text.getHeight());   
                }
            });
         Toast
```

EDIT:

You need to log the height synchronously using the post method of the textView

```
  final TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
          text.setText(s);
          final ViewTreeObserver observer= text.getViewTreeObserver();
           observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                 hieght = text.getHeight();   
                }
            });
  text.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             Log.d("Hieght", ""+hieght); //hieght is the variable you used to get the height in the onGlobalLayout

        }
    });
```

Comment: Seems to be working, the values should be correct but I'm not able to get the height from the onGlobalLayout() function, how would I go about that? I tried creating a variable outside the function but wasn't able to store it

Comment: I used a static variable and I was able to get the height value, didn't before for some reason, anyways I tried inputting different heights for the toast by using linebreaks in the text, it didn't give the right position, the Toast was floating off by some distance, the height I was given didn't match the height for the toast, plus the first button press always gives height = 0

Comment: @Raddy there is some padding within the toast so you wont really gonna get the right hieght you need to add the top and buttom padding from the toast

Comment: Oh ok, I see your point, but how can I convert 8dp to pixels? I'm using Samsung Galaxy SII so 480x800

Comment: Ok got it, I used 24 and its giving the correct result but there is still one issue, on the first button press the height is always zero

Comment: Make sure to remove the listener in the callback or you'll get a memory leak.